# Dadas dos coordenadas conseguir la elevación acumulada

Tags: google-maps

Tengo dos coordenadas y me gustaría saber alguna alternativa a google maps o a osm que indique el desnivel acumulado o la altura acumulada en coche para así poder escoger entre una ruta u otra.

He encontrado alternativas como graphhopper (da la información pero hay límite de peticiones) o mapquest(da la elevación en los puntos y no la acumulada).

Google maps me da la altitud acumulada pero tiene limitaciones de peticiones en la versión gratuita. Yo necesitaría una miles de consultas diarias.

¿Hay alguna otra alternativa gratuita que pueda dar la información siendo en coche?

Me han comentado que el IGN de España da la altura acumulada. ¿Podría alguien indicarme como se haría la consulta?

Comment: Hay algún impedimento para usar google maps?

Comment: Podrias intentar con Open Layers 3, tienen un API para datos de elevación, aunque creo usan los datos de OSM por detrás del telón.

Comment: Si, el uso de google maps tiene restricciones de peticiones.

Comment: No veo muy probable encontrar un *servicio* escalable y gratuito. Tendrías que moverte a tener tu propia infraestructura y cartografía. Por favor, edita la pregunta y especifica bien los requisitos/peticiones diarias/etc para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: Ok, gracias. Acabo de editarla

Comment: No creas @rnd, En todos los países, habrá un instituto Geográfico que se encargue de servir este tipo de datos. En concreto el usuario podría buscar en su Instituto Geográfico si tienen implementados servicios WCS que contengan Modelos digitales de elevaciones. Aquí un ejemplo de servicio WCS de modelos digitales de elevaciones para España http://www.ign.es/wcs/mdt?request=GetCapabilities&service=WCS

Comment: Otra alternativa sería conseguir tu propio MDT (Hay formas de hacerlo teniendo cartografía base, puntos de cota, etc.) y usar PostgreSQL/Postgis + backend y hacer tu propio servicio (JSON,...)

Comment: Intereseante @JoseHermosillaRodrigo, en Argentina tenemos el Instituto Geografico Nacional pero no tienen un servicio asi. Claro que puedes obtener la cartografia y armar tu propia infraestructura.

Comment: Acabo de mirarlo y tienes razón, el IGN de Argentina no proporciona servicios WCS... :( De todas formas teniendo un buen modelo de elevaciones y un backend (Ya sea Geoserver con el que se puede implementar el servicio WCS, o WPS (Con el que podemos implementar procesos http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wps)). Estos servicios nombrados son estándares para servir información geográfica a través de internet.

Comment: Ok, entonces, si quisiese obtener la altitud acumulada entre dos coordenadas ¿que tendría que hacer con el modelo IGN de España y el archivo que me indicas?

Comment: Es muy largo de explicar, muchos pasos, ...¿Sabes algo de servicios web, postgreSQL, PostGIS? En resumen podrías usar postgreSQL y postGIS como repositorio de ese MDT  (ráster), y utilizar las funciones de postGIS para extraer la altura acumulada y servirla a través de un servicio web. Si lo que deseas hacer es para  España existe el servicio WCS comentado antes para obtener las alturas de forma individual (1 punto cada X distancia sobre el perfil)

Comment: Es más podrías utilizar el servicio WPS qué ya tienen implementado funcionalidades para obtener el perfil http://www.ign.es/wps-analisis/servicios?request=GetCapabilities&service=WPS (descripción del servicio). Si tu caso solo tiene que ver con España te podría poner algún ejemplo de como explotar estos servicios.

Comment: Si, mi caso solo sería para España. Si es posible me gustaría ver algunos ejemplos para tener algo de referencia. Gracias

Comment: Aqí tienes un poco la descripción del servicio WPS, http://www.idee.es/resources/documentos/RD_wps_v1_0.pdf , en concreto a tí te interesa la operación `GetProfileTxt`, páginas 8 y 9.

Comment: Ok, gracias. No consigo entender como se haría la consulta para obtener la altura acumulada utilizando GetProfieTxT. ¿Podrías ponerme un ejemplo?

Comment: No sabría por donde empezar y además no hay la suficiente documentación. ¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Answer (score 5):

*No queda claro si necesitas una alternativa por que no puedes/quieres usar google maps, o por si no sabes como hacero. Como sea, la pregunta esta etiquetada como [google-maps](/questions/tagged/google-maps). Ademas, como no especificas un lenguaje, pongo un ejemplo en javascript; Pero ten en cuenta que de fondo hay una API Web que puedes consumir desde cualquier lenguaje*

Con google maps, puedes hacerlo usando la Elevation API para obtener la altitud de una path o camino dado. Luego con todas las altitudes hacer la sumatoria del valor absoluto de la diferencia entre las altitudes.

En el siguiente ejemplo, utilizo la Directions API para obtener la ruta entre dos ciudades. Esta me devuelve una estructura complicada que convierto a una serie de puntos Lat,Lon con los cuales consulta la Elevation API.

Debes tener en cuenta que la Elevation API tiene un limite de la cantidad de puntos que puedes solicitar por pedido, por lo que si el recorrido es muy largo (con mas de 256 puntos aprox) deberas hacer mas de una consulta para obtener todas las altitudes.

Este ejemplo es una aproximacion para exponer las APIs de google que puedes usar, deje algunos comentarios en el codigo:

```js
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
var elevator = new google.maps.ElevationService;
var directionsDisplay;
var map;

initMap();
calcRoute();

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 5,
    center: {
      lat: -33,
      lng: -63
    }
  });
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
}

function calcRoute() {
  var start = "Buenos Aires";
  var end = "Junin";

  var request = {
    origin: start,
    destination: end,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  };

  directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      // convertimos la respuesta en un path
      var path = dirsToPath(result);

      // solicitamos la altitud de los puntos
      elevator.getElevationAlongPath({
        'path': path,
        'samples': path.length
      }, plotElevation);

      // mostramos el path en el mapa
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
    }
  });
}

// aqui se calcula la altitud acumulada
function plotElevation(elevations, status) {
  var elem = document.getElementById('elevation');
  if (status !== 'OK') {
    elem.innerHTML = 'Hubo un problema cargando elevation: ' +
      status;
    return;
  }

  // aqui se hace la sumatoria de las diferencias
  var accum = 0;
  var prev = elevations[0].elevation
  for (var i = 0; i < elevations.length; i++) {
    accum += Math.abs(elevations[i].elevation - prev);
    prev = elevations[i].elevation;    
  }

  elem.innerHTML = accum.toFixed(2) + " metros acumulados";
}

// convierte las directions en un path basado en overview_path
// que es un aproximacion del path real y tiene pocos puntos
function dirsToPath(directions) {
  var result = [];
  var path = directions.routes[0].overview_path
  path.forEach(function(step) {
    console.log(step)
    result.push({
          lat: step.lat(),
          lng: step.lng()
    });
  });
  return result;
}

// convierte las directions en un path basado en el path real
// que el "path real" y tiene mucho puntos. Posiblemente, lo mejor 
// seria calcular la altura acumulada Step x Step 
// esta funcion no se usa, la dejo como guia
function dirsToPath2(directions) {
  var result = [];
  var legs = directions.routes[0].legs;
  legs.forEach(function(item) {
    item.steps.forEach(function(step) {
      step.path.forEach(function(path) {
        result.push({
          lat: path.lat(),
          lng: path.lng()
        });
      });
    });
  });    
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 150px;
}
#elevation {
  font-size: x-large;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyACJapLIVhm-uVWitwICh24232jYdkP1SQ"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="elevation"></div>
```

Vale aclarar que estas dos ciudades estan en una llanura.

Comment: Hola, el problema es que no puedo utilizar google maps porque hay restricción de peticiones y voy a realizar muchas. Lo que me gustaría saber es si hay alguna alternativa a este que proporcione la altura acumulada

Comment: Te refieres a que hay un limite en la oferta gratuita cierto? Por que la oferta paga se puede escalar casi limitadamente. Como sea, seria medio raro que encuentres algún servicio que te de escalabilidad gratuita.

Comment: Si, me refiero de forma gratuita. ¿Habrá algún tipo de algoritmo que me calcule la altitud acumulada sabiendo la altitud en algún punto intermedio?